# Where do I find xcolor.sty from MikTeX

Tags: color, miktex

I am using MikTeX Version 2.9. When I am trying to convert the `doxygen` comments to PDF, the MikTeX couldn't able to download `xcolor.sty`. I am running `MikTeX Package Manager (Admin).exe` and specifying the   `mirror.kku.ac.th`, which was live when I verified online from the following URL: `https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories`

This is how the connection settings are configured

[image]

After that it always says couldn't connect to server.

[image]

Could someone help me on this, how to download the `xcolor.sty`. 
I went ahead and downloaded `xcolor` package from the following path: `https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor` which has a `xcolor.zip`. But that doesn't contains `xcolor.sty` file. Can we show this zip package to the update manager?

Altenatively I do not mind to download all the packages (If it is 1 or 2 GB) and use the local path.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can it be that you mixed proxy server and mirror? A proxy server is a server driven by your institution you usually need to login. Usually it's url is something like proxy.my-domain.de with special port given by your institute. Check box Authenitification if you need to log in. The Mirror is one ftp server containing MiKTe sources ...

Comment: Download MikTeX **Net Installer** then download and install full packages. Another suggestion is to download TeXlive
http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/texlive.iso

Comment: Proxy setting was wrong as identified by Kurt. One of my colleague has helped me to provide correct proxy setting.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you mixed **proxy server** and **mirror**?

A proxy server is a server driven by your institution/university you usually need to login. Usually it's url is something like `proxy.my-domain.de` with special port given by your institute. Check box `Authenitification ...` if you need to log in.

The Mirror is one of several ftp server, for example url `http://mirror.kku.ac.th`,  containing MiKTeX sources ...